# Use a Video as Landing Page background (as seen in Spotify) on Android

Tags: android, performance, webview, gif

I'd like to set a video as background to a view. I have one solution, which involves loading a .GIF. This is a great solution, but the quality is very low, because the video has lots of movement which is not suited for .GIF files.
Is there a better solution?

Comment: Check the answer given in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33458793/set-a-video-as-background