# set a video as background on mobile app unity

Tags: c#, android, ios, video, unity-game-engine

I am making a login screen for a mobile app in unity3d, that has a video keep on playing in the background and can work on iOS and Android. I have searched online and found out movie texture doesn't work on mobile.

Currently I only can play a video using Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie, but it is not what I want. I want the video playing and still see the text and have button to click.

I see similar post [Set a video as background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33458793/set-a-video-as-background?answertab=active#tab-top). But I am using C#. Does anyone know how to do this in unity? Many Thanks!

Comment: You'll need a plugin for this. EasyMovieTexture works fairly well and is about $30. Note that there is no other solution at the moment from Unity.

Comment: Is this the one you mean https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/10032. Its $65... Where did you get the $30 one?

Comment: My bad, the guy doubled the price. I remember paying something like 30 to $40. Back then it was almost implemented but working. I guess he added the 4 or 5 missing methods and double the price.

Comment: ah, I see. So pricy... But thank you for your info!